# How to move logic to show UITableViewRowAction from delegate method to View Model (MVVM Architecture)

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift, rxdatasources

I'm learn to use RxSwift and RxDataSource to separate business logic from View Controller (using MVVM).

Suppose I want to create table view like in the Mail App in iOS, when user swipe left, there are **delete button** and **More button**.

In the normal MVC, I have to implement delegate method `editActionsForRowAt`.

`public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?`

```
        var swipeActions = [UITableViewRowAction]()
        let removeAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { [weak self] (action, indexPath) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            strongSelf.deleteBankAccountTrigger.onNext(indexPath)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        swipeActions.append(removeAction)

        if *cellIsNotDefault* {
            let makeDefaultAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Make Default") { [weak self] (action, indexPath) in
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
                strongSelf.makeBankAccountDefaultTrigger.onNext(indexPath)
            }

            makeDefaultAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            swipeActions.append(makeDefaultAction)
        }

        return swipeActions
```

I don't know how to move logic **cellIsNotDefault** from the delegate to ViewModel. Because I think the logic to show/hide `SwipeAction` button should be in ViewModel.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you.

Update:

I tried to use RxDataSources, but still no clue for custom swipe action. For delete action, I can use `tableView.rx.itemDeleted` method to subscribe to it. But if I want to subscribe to the custom Swipe action (like my Make Default action). How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, viewModel should contain just data that are displayed by particular view. So I'm not sure if viewModel should contain information about behaviour of your view ( in this case it means that your cell have some action ). Maybe I would encapsulate this logic to the model itself. I guess that you get from API something like `isBankAccountDefault`. If you don't get this attribute straight from API and you need some logic to determine it. You can create computed property inside your model and put there * cellIsNotDefault * logic.

But if you insist on having it in viewModel, you can create Bool property `isBankAccountDefault` in viewModel. Then you will put logic * cellIsNotDefault * to formatter, that is creating that viewModel and set `isBankAccountDefault` value accordingly to * cellIsNotDefault * logic.

Comment: Thanks for answering @user3797599. Yes I agree the viewModel should contain just data. So the if else statement is still in the VC.

So I think, my question is wrong, I'm confused how to pass the value from ViewModel to the editActionsForRowAt method. I'm using [Clean Architecture Rx Swift](https://github.com/sergdort/CleanArchitectureRxSwift) Architecture Pattern. And the output is bind on the viewDidLoad. So how I get the value in the editActionsForRowAt?

Comment: Hi Jef, sorry for not getting back to your question. I'm not so familiar with  "Clean Architecture Rx Swift" and I didn't have time recently to get more into it. How did you solve your issue in the end?

Comment: I ended up using `PublishSubject` to trigger the input to the View Model. When the user select the option, I trigger the publish subject on next and passing the model.